# How to make HTML site fit all screen resolutions?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

`This is my CSS code;

```
/*homepage*/

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;700&family=PT+Sans&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

html {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-size: 18px;
}

#hero {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.350),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.350)), url('./bilder/welcome.jpg') no-repeat center / cover ;
    color: white;
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    margin: right auto;
    float: right;
    }

    .navbar nav {
        display: block;
        padding-right: 12px;
    }
    

    .navbar a {
        color: white;
        font-size: 0.9rem;
        font-weight: bold; 
        text-decoration: none;
        line-height: 60px;
        padding: 0.4em 0.9em;
        border: 2px solid;
        border-color: white;
        border-radius: 20px;
        margin: 9px;
        transition: 0.3s;
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 0px 3px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) 0px 3px 6px;
    }

    .navbar a:hover {
        color:black;
        background: rgb(177, 108, 77);
        border-color: black;
        
    }

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    max-width: 1200px; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    text-align: left;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container .hero-text h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.3rem;
}

.container .hero-text h2 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.container .hero-text p {
    font-family: 'PT Sans';
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    max-width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.container .hero-text a {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    background-color: lightgray;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0.5em 1.2em;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    transition: 0.3s;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 0px 3px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) 0px 3px 6px;
}

.container .hero-text a:hover {
    background: rgb(177, 108, 77);
    color: black;
}

.container .bilde-credit p {
    opacity: 30%;
    color: brown;
    font-size: 1.0rem;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { 
    html {
        font-size: 10px;
    }

}

/*topical siden*/
p{
    font-size: small;
}

.container #text {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

h1{
    float: right;
}
.footer{
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000d1a;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.topical{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.350),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.350)), url('/bilder/topical.jpg') no-repeat center / cover ;
    color: white;
}


.teknologi{  /*class laget for å justere på bildet*/
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20%;


}

.footer a {
    color: white; /*gir hyperlenkene i footeren en hvit farge framfor blå, for å skape en god kontrast*/


}



.science {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20%;
}
```

`I am struggling to fit my webpage to all screens. When I inspect the page everything just goes over each other, the text, pictures, the footer, etc. I will glady appreciate if someone can check over my code.

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Topical siden</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <!--Link som referer siden til stylesheet-->
    </head>
    <body class="topical">
        <!-- NAVBAR -->
        <div class="navbar">
            <nav>
                <a href="index.html">Hjem</a>   
                <a href="kafe.html">Kafé</a>
                <a href="booking.html">Booking</a>
                <a href="accessibility.html">Accessibility</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <h1>Topical page - Technology and society </h1>
        <!--Tittel-->
        <div class="container">
            <div id="text">
                <h2>The interplay between technology and society</h2>
                <!--Undertittel-->
                <p>
                    <!--Paragraf-->
                    1.2            <img src="/bilder/workplace.png" alt="Bilde av samfunn og teknologi" width="300" height="241" class="teknologi"> <!--BILDE, STØRRELSE + CLASS DEFINERT FOR BILDE FOR Å BRUKE I CSS. HENTET FRA https://blog.vantagecircle.com/technology-in-the-workplace/ -->
                    The evolution of technology is a fundamental part of society, and it is safe to say that we have benefited from it. In the past we relied on books, but now we have phones that can quickly find answers to our questions. Our workplace has also become safer and more efficient with the introduction of automated technology (Ellingrud, 2018), but it has also contributed to the elimination of certain jobs. However, a study of census conducted over the course of 140 years suggests technology has created more jobs than it has destroyed (Stewart et al., 2015, p. 3). It has also helped maintain jobs through difficult times. Thanks to the communication channels technology provides, jobs could still be done from home during the COVID-19 pandemic. In the same way society progresses, it also starts valuing new things: and what becomes important to us, becomes important to technology. One example being that once we realized the effects of climate change, we started caring about creating sustainable technologies. 
                    Societal values can also have a negative impact. Society has long been obsessed with “the perfect body”, and since it is widely advertised, it has inevitably migrated to the internet and become a part of that world. Now we not only see it in the “real” world, but also on our phones constantly. One could argue that its increased exposure intensifies the pressure of fulfilling the unrealistic body standards our society glorifies, which can lead to body image issues and eating disorders.
                    <br>
                    <br>            <!--IKKE BRUK BR TAG FOR Å LAGE ROM I AVSNITTENE -->
                <p>
                    <img src="/bilder/science.jpeg" alt="Bilde av diverse ting samfunnet og teknologi " width="250" height="241" class="science"> <!--BILDE, STØRRELSE + CLASS DEFINERT FOR BILDE FOR Å BRUKE I CSS. HENTET FRA https://community.thriveglobal.com/the-relationship-between-science-technology-and-society/ -->
                    1.4
                    Taking responsibility and attempting to foresee the possible future outcomes of your creation should be an important part of every innovator’s process. Innovations can have serious societal implications and for that reason it is only fair to expect innovators to take this into consideration. However, we should be somewhat reasonable to which degree we hold them accountable, and that is because RRI is not an easy process. It requires research, cooperation and communication – not just in the form of discussion between innovators, but also in the shape of feedback from society. Society plays a significant role in the development of innovations, as the citizens can bring a unique, diversified perspective that innovators could forget to consider. If we fail to properly communicate our criticisms, we are, arguably, partially responsible.
                    Even a well-intended innovation that had RRI strongly implemented into its process, can be turned “evil”. Technology is not inherently bad/harmful in itself – it is what we choose to do with it that can make it such. Sadly, there are people who take advantage of innovator’s inventions and “villainize” them in ways they weren’t meant to be utilized. Examples of this include the internet: the internet is good because it provides methods of communication and supplies information, but it has also become a damaging place used for other purposes like cyber-bullying and human trafficking recruitment. With a quick Google search, we can see that laws have been set in place to prevent this, and that there can be severe penalties for committing these offenses. However, I would argue that these crimes are hard to regulate because of the anonymity the internet offers us, and because it is not taken as seriously as other “real life” crimes.
                    No invention will ever be flawless, and unintended consequences will likely surface regardless – but by practicing RRI we can reduce the severity and number of them. 
                </p>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- FOOTER UNDER + KILDER -->
        <div class="footer">
            <footer>
                Sources: <br>
                Ellingrud, K. (2018). The Upside Of Automation: New Jobs, Increased Productivity And Changing Roles For Workers. Retrieved from <a href="https://www.forbes.com/sites/kweilinellingrud/2018/10/23/the-upside-of-automation-new-jobs-increased-productivity-and-changing-roles-for-workers/?sh=5237c0d47df0">https://www.forbes.com/sites/kweilinellingrud/2018/10/23/the-upside-of-automation-new-jobs-increased-productivity-and-changing-roles-for-workers/?sh=5237c0d47df0</a>
                <br> Stewart, I., De, D. & Cole, A. (2015). Technology and people: The great job-creating machine. 1-16. Retrieved from <a href="https://www2.deloitte.com/content/dam/Deloitte/uk/Documents/finance/deloitte-uk-technology-and-people.pdf>">https://www2.deloitte.com/content/dam/Deloitte/uk/Documents/finance/deloitte-uk-technology-and-people.pdf></a> 
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried to use % instead of px and vh but the problem still won't be solved.

Comment: Can you post your css too? Do you hear about media queries?

Comment: Think I just added the CSS now.

Comment: I'll suggest you to search ' how to make a site responsible' on google, you can find a lot of tutorials

Comment: Here is examples how make responsive views [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) if you don't want to search yourself